# Time scheduling of programs execution in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I would like to create in Visual Basic (using Visual Studio) a tool that enables you to become a working definition (program), when to run, schedule execution, application start-up, record of execution, when it began, when it ended.. so on.

Anyone know how I can do this?

I need your help.
It is very important for me.
Thank you very much everyone.
I appreciate it.

---

I have uploaded in a textbox a file( the path of file .exe from my computer).

I have set the start time of the file's ececution.

I want the command that gets the file(.exe) from the textbox and sets it running at the specific time, when I press the button.

Does anyone know that command;

That is the command, i have used, but is not working.:

MyProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = TextBox1.Text
               MyProcess.start()

Comment: George_Pap, what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you provide a specific question we may be able to help out.. What do you need to know exactly?

Comment: What kind of environment are you in? Is this something you could accomplish with cron?

Comment: I am still at the beginning. I want to make a program that sets out to do something a certain time and be done. For example at five o'clock to begin running an application installed on my computer and six o'clock to finish.I am working in Microsoft Visual Studio environment.
If anyone knows some basic easy steps to do that in Visual Basic language, will be grateful.

Comment: This is what scheduled tasks are for. Don't worry about the timing in your program: just make it do what you need it to. Once it's written, use the Scheduled Tasks feature in Windows to get it to run when and for as long as you want.

Comment: Does anyone know that?   --->
I have uploaded in a textbox a file( the path of file .exe from my computer).

I have set the start time of the file's ececution.

I want the command that gets the file(.exe) from the textbox and sets it running at the specific time, when I press the button.

That is the command, i have used, but is not working.:

MyProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = TextBox1.Text MyProcess.start()

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for some variant of Windows, you should look at Task Scheduler as it is part of modern versions of Windows.